# Prove that the cross product is a bilinear form

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, cross-product

I want to show that the application

$$\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} \quad \text{given by} \quad \phi(u, v)=u \times v$$

It is bilinear

In first place, note that

\begin{align*}
    \phi(\alpha u+ \beta v), w &= (\alpha u+ \beta v) \times w \\
    &=\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k\\ 
\alpha u_{1}+\beta v_{1} & \alpha u_{2}+\beta v_{2} &\alpha u_{3}+\beta v_{3} \\ 
w_{1} & w_{2} & w_{3}
\end{vmatrix}  \\
    &= \alpha \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k\\ 
 u_{1} & u_{2} & u_{3}\\ 
w_{1} & w_{2} & w_{3}
\end{vmatrix}+\beta \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k\\ 
 v_{1} & v_{2} &v_{3} \\ 
w_{1} & w_{2} & w_{3}
\end{vmatrix} \\
    &= \alpha(u \times v)+ \beta(v \times w)
\end{align*}

And you have one of the conditions to be bilinear, my question is with the other condition, it seems that if I verify that the application is symmetrical it would be quickly, but I do not see at all how to determine if it is symmetrical, any suggestions?

Comment: The cross product is anti-commutative, not commutative. That is $u \times v = -(v \times u)$, which you could see by the fact that determinants flip sign when you exchange two rows. This will still give you linearity in the second variable. Or, you could do your very simple argument again in the third row, rather than the second.

Comment: The cross product of $2$ vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ is another vector there, not a scalar.